# Windows Authentication gives 401

Tags: reactjs, windows, authentication, ntlm

I am working in a project that uses Windows Authentication and it is my first experience with it. I have a backend ASP.NET Web Api setup with Windows Authentication, and it includes  AddNegotiate in my builder. I have a basic controller which returns username of the user.Here isthe codes from backend;

```
[ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class UserController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet(Name = "GetCurrentUser")]
        public string Get()
        {
            string name = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

            return name;
        }
    }
```

and my request from front-end(Reactjs) is;

```
 try {
      const response = await axios('https://localhost:7000/User');
      console.log(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.response);
    }
```

I always get 401 Unauthorized.The response header contains WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate, but no token provided.On the other hand in SwaggerUI with this endpoint I get my username successfully. What could be the root cause of this problem ?